# Responsive and resizing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Good Afternoon All,

I was wondering if you could point out where I have gone wrong please?

I am looking for the following to be more responsive on a mobile etc.

```
<section class="hero">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 sm-8" id="tennis-pic"><img src="assets/images/home-hero.jpg" class="home-hero"
                    alt="Tennis player being coached on court"></div>
            <div class="col-4 sm-4 blue-box">
                <h3 class="welcome">Welcome to Go Tennis System</h3>
                <p class="tips">Your home of Tips, Tricks, Training and of course Tennis</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <article>
        <div class="why-header">
            <h4>Why use our Go Tennis System service?</h4>
        </div>
        <p class="why-text">
            We offer a bespoke unique service. We do things digitally and at your pace.
            With our service we ask for a small donation that will be shared with a dogs charity and animal rescue
            charity,
            as part of our aim to give something back.
            We offer you the chance to upload your videos for coaching, tips and honest constructive feedback, this in
            turn will allow you to create your own video diary as well as improve and fine tune your skills.
            When we say we play the same game, just easier we mean at your pace and time scale. We cater for all ages as
            well as all levels, so if you’re a beginner that would like to play like a pro, come and give us a go, you
            will be glad you did.
        </p>
    </article>
```

I have the following CSS:

/* ------------------------------------------- Home Hero Image */

```
.hero {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.home-hero {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 110%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


/* ------------------------------------------- Home Welcome Box */

.blue-box { 
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #2a5490;
}

.welcome { 
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 45%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    top: 60px;
    right: auto;
    height: auto; 
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff; 
}


.tips { 
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    top: 60px;
    right: auto;
    height: auto; 
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff; 
}
```

Many thanks for your help in advance.

All the best

Andrew

My site that I am working on is [here](https://codepen.io/Andrewh1188/pen/YzZNZQQ?editors=1100)

Comment: the problem i am having is that I would like the image to take over the top part on a mobile and for it to push the blue box with the text inside underneath with the text centered please. Thank you

Comment: Andrew please can you provide a working example to make it easier for people to identity your issue. You can do this in an external playground like codepen or inside your question.

Comment: Use the vw and vh properties instead of using %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to amend your column classes to use the responsive syntax this way the column will span the width of the screen until the sm class kicks in at the next breakpoint.

- col-8 sm-8 = col-12 col-sm-8
- col-4 sm-4 = col-12 col-sm-4

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ will help you understand how the responsive classes work :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried this and it works beautifully. I was worried about changing things after getting them to work finally. I have had lots of "fun" with certain elements. 
The only thing I have an issue with is the white space down the side of the blue box because the image isn't resized in a way, would you know why this is please?

Thank you, Thank you, Thank you again. I really appreciate your help here